# Perlin worms for 2D cave generation

Tags: python, 2d, procedural-generation

I've been trying to make a 2D Minecraft-like game. I'm to the point where I've done the terrain generation, but I want to do cave generation now. I've experimented with Perlin noise, but found that the best I could get to were long connecting caves that never have dead ends. I then found out about perlin worms and realized it would be able to generate worm like caves.

I tried to do research on perlin worms, but there barely seems to be anything on it. Could you make a perlin worm function from a perlin noise function? If so, can you make it so that you could input a coordinate pair and it would return a value for that position like perlin noise functions?

Thanks in advance. All I need are ideas :)

Comment: I don't know whether there is any standardized way to create a Perlin worm, but in [this presentation](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1025191/Math-for-Game-Programmers-Digging) at 15:58 one possible way to create a Perlin worm is presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perlin worms can be created from Perlin noise or any other noise by just considering if the terrain is in a narrow range around the middle value of the terrain.

It is kind of hard to explain, so I've created a visual representation for how you transform a noise into worms.

### Original Noise (value noise)

[image: Noise]

### Transformed to Worms

[image: Worms]

Comment: This is what I settled on after some failed attempts :) The downside of this is the fact that the caves are too connected and there aren't really any dead ends, it just goes on and on forever unlike perlin worm caves in Minecraft. Thanks for the answer!